# Move Exchange Data Between Servers

Tags: exchange

--Moved from StackOverflow--

Our company has been using Comcast as our Exchange provider but we recently set up our own Exchange server running Exchange 2010.

We currently connect to Comcast via Exchange in Outlook.

I was wondering a best practice method for moving emails from accounts on Comcast to accounts on our new server. There are only 7 accounts however some have 30k emails as well as numerous calendar events and contacts.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty easy way to do this.

1. Change your MX records to your new Exchange server. I'd recommend changing your TTL on your MX records about 3-4 days in advance down to 5 minutes. Then make the change and wait 30 minutes to continue.
2. Export the mailbox from each client to a PST.
3. Setup your Outlook profiles to point to the new Exchange
4. Import the PSTs into Outlook

Comment: I did this on a whim and it worked! Thank you very much. *sits at the export screen of a 30k email account for the next year...*

Answer (score 0):

For 7 accounts I would try it with IMAP (if its possible).

Comment: IS there an import feature in the Exchange Server administration? (Sorry but I'm not much of an Exchange admin)

Comment: IMAP won't work. He mentioned calendar appointments. IMAP only does mail.

Comment: Thank you Jason. My solution doesn't work with calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 7 accounts, you might be able to convince Comcast to export each mailbox to a .PST file and send it to you. Those can then be reimported to the mailboxes on your system. That will get all the email and calender items. If they allow this, that would be great. I believe the powershell command for this is 'export-mailbox'.

Otherwise, you may be able to do something similar by way of Outlook itself. It won't be as complete, and I'm not 100% sure calender items would follow, but it can be done.